# Scala Type Mismatch in Eclipse but not in Console

Tags: eclipse, scala, type-mismatch

Eclipse currently throws an error for the following:

```
def sample(): String = {
  return "foo"
}
```

Throwing the error:

- type mismatch; found : java.lang.String("You will never hit here") required: 
   String

But when I am in the console, it works fine:

```
scala> def sample(): String = {return "foo"}
sample: ()String

scala> sample()
res0: String = foo
```

I am trying to figure out what may be causing this issue or what may be different in my Eclipse environment.

Comment: What versions are you using for Scala, Eclipse, Scala-Eclipse, JVM?

Answer (score 1):

restart your eclipse and try reloading the plugins .. nothing is wrong with the code